# Flickering screen with Kubuntu 13.10 on XPS 13 (Ivy Bridge)

Tags: 13.10, kubuntu, intel, xps

I installed Kubuntu 13.10 on an XPS 13 early 2013 model (L322X), having had to pass the 'nomodeset' parameter to the installer.  Strangely, I only had to do this after I updated the Windows installation to 8.1.

Without nomodeset, and using the 'intel' Xorg driver, both the installer screen and the login screen of the actual OS look something like old CRT monitors would show images if you passed in an unsupported refresh rate.

This is a really bad video of how it looks: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4jxAfLTaT4 .  Sorry for the lack of quality.

Now, in the installed OS itself, if I boot with 'nomodeset' and use the 'fbdev' driver, I can get Xorg to work.  However, this isn't optimal of course.

What's happening?  As I said, the installer only started doing this without 'nomodeset' after I updated the Windows partition to Windows 8.1.

Also, if the intel driver is used with 'nomodeset', this error appears:

```
[     4.224]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[     4.224] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, HD Graphics,
        HD Graphics 2000, HD Graphics 3000, HD Graphics 2500,
        HD Graphics 4000, HD Graphics P4000, HD Graphics 4600,
        HD Graphics 5000, HD Graphics P4600/P4700, Iris(TM) Graphics 5100,
        HD Graphics 4400, HD Graphics 4200, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200
[     4.225] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     4.225] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     4.225] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     4.225] (++) using VT number 7

[     4.228] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     4.228] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried the latest kernel as specified here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds and the flickering went away.  However then the backlight didn't work.  I'll assume it's an ongoing problem that will fix itself when 3.12 makes it into Saucy and the devs get a chance to play with it (I can't be the only one dual-booting Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu).